# The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters,

Tags: c#, string, .net-4.0

Here is the code i am using. It works fine when i run locally. but when i drop all my dlls to a remote machine i keep getting this error:

The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

```
   public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        if (cipherText == string.Empty)
            return string.Empty;

        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(
            new byte[] { 0x50, 0x00, 0x41, 0x00, 0x43, 0x00, 0x43, 0x00, 0x41, 0x00, 0x52, 0x00, 0x34, 0x00, 0x32, 0x00,
                0x35, 0x00, 0x34, 0x00, 0x36, 0x00, 0x38, 0x00, 0x37, 0x00, 0x34, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, },
            new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        byte[] decryptedData = Decrypt(cipherBytes, pdb.GetBytes(32), pdb.GetBytes(16));
        
        return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedData);
    }
```

Can someone please help me figure out? i have check the machine and it seems that machine has .NET 4.5 and higher. and I have built my application on .Net 4.0. Other than that i am not able to figure out where is the error

Comment: The error is clear. `cipherText` is not valid base64. There is nothing in the code you have shown that can fix that. Maybe you are making a wrong assumption, maybe the caller is doing something wrong.

Comment: Its just a string i am entering. I have debugged in my local machine and its returning correctly the decoded value. Problem is when i run the same on a different machine. and also it was working fine till two days back.

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is. Did it ever occur to you to actually look at the value of `cipherText`? How exactly was that value generated in the first place?

Comment: Garbage In, Garbage Out. Classic programming problem. Don't get hung up on "it should work". If you get that error then that string is not valid base64. You say it works when you plug in a value but when running remotely the input will originate from a different source so it is not a valid argument.

Comment: actually i am using the same cipertext when debugging and also on the other machine too. That's my user name i have encoded and passing it as cipher text to decode back as my username to login to a external application.

Comment: Maybe something with encoding? I am absolutely not an expert on this, but is it possible that the Cultures on both systems differ? Can this might lead to a malformed string?

Comment: Well let's see the value then.

Comment: Sorry to ask this question. i am very naive in this too. What do you mean by different cultures?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=net-6.0 I doubt that's the issue. Please can we have a [mcve] with your actual value